# Dependent can stay in UK till end date of visa if main applicant leave UK before end date of visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa

Main applicant suppose to leave UK before end of visa, how about dependent visa holder staying in UK?

Can dependent visa holder can stay in UK without the main applicant till the end of VISA date?

Comment: Which visa specifically?  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-8-family-members AFAIK, typically the main applicant must also be in the UK but knowing the type of visa you refer to will get you a better answer

Comment: TIER 2 ICT VIsa

Comment: My reading of the information under ‘Period of grant’ https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/769441/PBS_Dependant_Guidance_01-2019.pdf#page10 is that a dependent’s visa expiry date will typically be the same as the main visa holder’s. I don’t see anything in the rules that says a dependent cannot stay in the UK until the expiry date, even if the main applicant is not in the UK. But it could depend on the circumstances eg if the main applicant’s visa has been curtailed. Can you edit your question to explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My partner project planned to close in July. My partner may be return to home country or employer will plan to put other project. In case my partner is leaving, can i stay in UK and continue my job till end of my visa date. As far as i know my partner employer will not convey to UKVI about leaving, because partner have a visa so employer mostly try to use the employee visa..

Comment: The employer is obliged to report if a sponsored migrant’s contract of, or for employment, or services or registration is terminated earlier than shown on their certificate of sponsorship (CoS).